# how to call main telegram api methods in php

Tags: php, api, telegram, mtp, mtproto

I want to use [main telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api) to [sign in](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.signIn) and manage telegram account from **php** code.

I read telegram documents and read all last topics and related questions like:

[Calling Telegram API to create a feedreader bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045265/calling-telegram-api-to-create-a-feedreader-bot)

[Accessing Telegram API via web-based client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913507/accessing-telegram-api-via-web-based-client)

[Using telegram API with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190994/using-telegram-api-with-php)

[Using telegram API with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190994/using-telegram-api-with-php)

[Telegram API send messages with php or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213294/telegram-api-send-messages-with-php-or-javascript)

and .....

if your answer is " ... use bot api " or " ... use telegram cli " I should say it's not  good answer for my problem!

I want sign in as different users account and manage them.

tnx a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement authorization using a Telegram API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661644/how-to-implement-authorization-using-a-telegram-api)

Answer (score 1):

1) get familiar with telegram API by studying existing source code.

2) Also write your own code to generate your Auth_key (see telegram api site)

3) build your own parser to handle conversion of byte streams into telegram types. you will need this to be able to interact with telegram servers

4) download a copy of webogram and run it locally with console.logs embedded in the JavaScript, particularly in the mtproto.js and other here: webogram\app\js\lib\

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/32809138/44080